# Incompleteness of Second-order PA

Tags: model-theory

I'm trying to reconcile Godel's Incompleteness Theorem with the fact that $\mathbb{N}$ is the canonical model of second-order PA. If there is a statement $S$ that is undecidable in PA, then it would seem that PA + S and PA + $\lnot S$ are both consistent models of Peano Arithmetic, contradicting the uniqueness of $\mathbb{N}$. What am I missing here?

A related question is the notion of "true but unprovable": what is the basis for saying that an unprovable statement in arithmetic is true, when it can't be proven from the axioms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ask about things that are "true but unprovable". This does indeed sound paradoxical: if I say that $\alpha$ is true but unprovable, presumably I have proved that $\alpha$ is true - so what gives?

The issue is that when we say something like that, we're hiding details. Specifically, whenever someone says "provable," they mean "provable *from some axioms*". You'll often hear Goedel's incompleteness theorem stated as "There is a true but unprovable sentence." This is a vast, and misleading, simplification. Here's the right way to phrase it:

> $(*)\quad$ Suppose $X$ is a set of sentences in the language of arithmetic which isn't too complicated (technically: is *recursively enumerable*) and contains all the axioms of first-order PA. Then there is a sentence $\varphi$ such that - if $X$ is consistent - $\varphi$ is true and not provable from $X$.

$(*)$ is provable in PA, incidentally. *By the way, "PA" can be replaced throughout with much much weaker systems, but I'm not going to focus on that here. Also, a historical note: $(*)$ is actually **Rosser's** improvement of Goedel's original theorem.*

Note that $\varphi$ depends on $X$! There isn't a single $\varphi$ which is "true but unprovable" in some universal sense; rather, each (consistent, recursively enumerable) theory $X$ yields its own $\varphi$.

Moreover, the proof that $\varphi$ is true takes place not in $X$, but rather in the theory PA+"$X$ is consistent" (note the hypothesis that $X$ be consistent in the statement above). So - as long as $X$ is consistent! - $\varphi$ is true, but the only way we *know* that $\varphi$ is true is by accepting PA+"$X$ is consistent", and this goes beyond what $X$ itself can do.

---

Incidentally, how does this interact with second-order PA? Well, the issue is that second-order logic is terrible: it has no complete proof system (and that's just scratching the surface). From a collection $X$ of first-order sentences, I can *effectively enumerate* the things $X$ proves - just search through all possible proofs! Since second-order logic doesn't have a complete proof system, though, that's not a possibility. So it doesn't really make sense to speak of something being "provable" from a collection of second-order sentences, at least not in the way we're used to thinking about proofs.

We could try to do the following: take $X$ to be the set of *first-order consequences* of second-order PA. The problem, now, is that this $X$ **is not recursively enumerable**, so Goedel's theorem doesn't apply to it.

Comment: IIRC second-order arithmetic can be formulated in ZFC, which is first order. How does that affect this (if at all)?

Comment: @eyeballfrog It doesn't affect this, really. Any given *model* $V$ of ZFC has what it thinks are the arithmetic consequences of second-order PA (this is just a fancy way to say "true arithmetic"), but that set of sentences will not be recursively enumerable; and ZFC *as a set of axioms* isn't enough to decide when one second-order sentence implies another (e.g. the Continuum Hypothesis is undecidable in ZFC, but there's a second-order sentence which is true in every model iff CH is true).

Comment: Well now I know how PA feels because I'm sure that's true but not sure what it means. Might have to ask about it later.

Comment: You say "if $X$ is consistent, $\varphi$ is true but not provable from $X$". Where does this notion of "truth" come from, if not from $X$ itself?

Comment: I reread your answer and I realize now that the truth of $\varphi$ comes from assuming the consistency of $X$, not from $X$ itself. But on the other hand, if we assume the inconsistency of $X$, then can't we also prove $\varphi$, since an inconsistent theory proves everything? If that's the case, how can it be that $\varphi$ is provable whether or not we assume the consistency of $X$, yet not provable from $X$?

Comment: @JeffreyDawson You have to distinguish your theories! We have two theories we're interested in: PA+Con(X), and X. Now PA+Con(X) does indeed prove "$\varphi$ is true, regardless of whether $X$ is consistent" (this is just a fancy way of saying "$\varphi$" :P). And if X is inconsistent, then certainly X proves $\varphi$. But what if X is consistent? Just because PA+Con(X) proves $\varphi$, doesn't mean that X proves $\varphi$; and indeed the weaker theory PA does **not** prove $\varphi$ in general ($\varphi$ is roughly "X is consistent" - not obviously true!).

Comment: That is, we have two arguments: "If X is consistent, then $\varphi$ is true" (this is proved in PA) and "If X is inconsistent, then $\varphi$ is *provable in X*" (also proved in PA). But note that "provable in X" and "true" are (from the perspective of PA) not the same thing: PA does *not* prove "$\varphi\iff Prov_X(\varphi)$".

Comment: I'm sorry for opening a 2 year old thread. Firstly, I am assuming that everywhere that you have mentioned PA, you mean the first order PA. Can someone explain what will happen if we take X to be the set of first order sentences that comprise PA itself? In that case PA+Con(X) just becomes PA+Con(PA), right? In other words, if we assume that PA is consistent, then we can prove $\varphi$, but PA alone cannot prove the consistency of $\varphi$? Am I correct in saying this? Can someone elaborate?

Do we know whether PA is consistent or not, or even if it is know-able?

Comment: @EkanshdeepGupta Yes, "PA" above means first-order PA. PA does not prove Con(X) when X=PA (assuming PA is consistent in the first place!), but PA + "PA is consistent" does of course. As to whether the consistency of PA is "knowable," that depends on what you mean by "know" - presumably we know something if we can prove it in a "reasonably simple" system, but what does "reasonably simple" mean?

Answer (score 3):

Godel's Incompleteness Theorem is about *first-order* PA.  The usual natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ is the unique (up to isomorphism) model for second-order PA, but no set of first-order axioms can produce a unique model unless that model is finite (which $\mathbb{N}$ isn't).

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere - I cannot find where for the moment ! - that Second Order Peano Arithmetic (=PA²) is indeed incomplete.

And there exists a deductive system for first order logic, which is complete **but not for full models**, i.e. models in which universal quantification over subsets is interpreted as over **all** subsets. In other words, second order predicates must be interpreted in a subcollection of subsets for theses models, in order to get a complete system (I think this is equivalent to a first order reduction to second order logic).

Now if PA² is incomplete, this only means that there exists a sentence $\phi$ such that PA² proves neither $f$ neither $\neg \phi$. By completeness, this means that there exists models $M_1$ and $M_2$ of $PA²$ such that $\phi$ is true in $M_1$ and $\neg\phi$ is true in $M_2$ !

However, $\mathbb N$ is the only **full** model of PA² : these models will thus have to be "non-standard", in that they will be conceived as applying second order quantification to a strict subcollection of subsets.